# Subtracting from variable when element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The situation:**
Hey everyone, I'm at a total loss here. I'm new to Javascript and Jquery and am trying to build a functional donation form.  What I have are three textboxes--each label as "Cart Item".  Each represents a fund that someone can donate to.  The textbox is setup so they can type in the dollar amount of how much they want to donate.  Then, on the bottom, there's a calculateSum function that totals up the values in the three textboxes.  Here is the code I used to do that:

The textboxes:

```
<input type="text" id="donation" class="donation form-control" placeholder="0.00" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);" onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);" maxlength="13">
```

The total is displayed in a span tag with the id #total:

```
<span id="total" onchange="numbersWithCommas()">0.00</span>
```

Here is the code that makes the total function work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".donation").each(function() {

         $(this).keyup(function(){
              calculateSum();
         });
      });

    });

function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".donation").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#total").html(sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(^\d{1,3}|\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:$|\.))/g, '$1,'));
    }
</script>
```

I've also added the option to delete items/funds in the "cart" by clicking the "X's" to the right.  The code used to accomplish that:

```
    <a href="#" class="dr" title="Remove item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a>

<script>
$('.dr').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut( 1000, function() { 
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

You can see it working here: http://saulmarquez.com/test/cart-delete.html

**The PROBLEM:**
If I type a value in a textbox and then delete that item from the cart (using the X button to the right), that value is not subtracted from the cart's total.  I need it subtracted from the total when it's deleted.

I'm really not sure how to go about doing it.  I think it'd have to be part of the following script:

```
<script>
$('.dr').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut( 1000, function() { 
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm not really sure.  Like I said, I'm new to this stuff.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: FYI you have 2 versions of jQuery loading on page, remove the tag with 1.4.4 in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the calculateSum function after you remove the element

```
<script>
$('.dr').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut( 1000, function() { 
        $(this).remove();
        calculateSum();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 that's much easier than what I've started to do to actually subtract value.